# How To Check File Name from 2nd List Name in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to ask, how to check file if I've two list name's, like

```
cat /data/file1/ab.txt
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee

cat /data/file2/cd.txt
cc
dd
ee
aa
zz
xx
yy
```

and I want the output something like :

```
zz
xx
yy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort ab.txt > /tmp/file1
sort cd.txt > /tmp/file2
comm -13 /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

The `comm` program compares two files and shows the lines that they have in common or unique to each. `-13` means to omit the lines that are unique to file 1 and in common.

Comment: or `comm -13 <(sort ab.txt) <(sort cd.txt)`

Comment: @JS웃 That's what I typically use, but I don't think all shells implement `<(`, so I didn't show it.

Comment: True, it isn't POSIX compliant but should be safe here since OP tagged the question with `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep`:

```
$ grep -vf ab.txt cd.txt
zz
xx
yy
```

`-f` tells `grep` to obtain patterns from `ab.txt` and `-v` inverts the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' ab.txt cd.txt
```